# Taking variable from mysql record and saving it in python

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

I couldn't find answer for this so I asked here. I'm making an discord bot in python and I want to get variable in mysql based on two other. serverid and userid. If those 2 variables are found in same record then get third variable in record called level. If no user with combination of serverid and userid is found then set level variable to 1.

This is my code:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
serveridsql="serverid here"
useridsql="userid here"
val =(serveridsql, useridsql)
sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE serverid=%s AND userid=%s"
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(...)
```

I have no idea how to print or save third variable to another because in output I got an table and trying to print "myresult[2]" does not work.

Comment: `myresult` is a list of database rows that satisfied the search expression.  If only one record was found, then `myresult[2]` does not exist.

Comment: Try printing myresult to be sure of what it conatins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do a for loop to iterate over the rows in the table you get in myresult:

```
for row in myresult:
    print("userid = ", row[0], )
    print("serverid = ", row[1])
```

Otherwise please show me how your table looks like. You can add dummy data instead of real data before posting.

Answer (score 0):

`myresult` is a python `dataframe`. You can try the following-

```
import numpy as np
myresult['new_level'] = np.where(myresult['serverid'].isnull() & myresult['userid'].isnull(), 1, myresult['level']))
```

• **numpy.where(condition, x, y)** - Return elements chosen from x or y depending on condition.
When True, yield x, otherwise yield y.